# Add Space Separator to input with type number only

Tags: html, css

I have a project with angular 4, 
I have a form in angular materia, I need to have an input with type number ( i can't use text )
during digit number ( is a phone number ) after the third element, i want see a space.

that is my code

```
<input matInput type="number" placeholder="--- -------"  
formControlName="telephone"  >
```

example:
** I want insert 36457637**

** I want to see in the input 364 57637**

Does anyone know how is possible that?

Comment: No, that is not possible. The value of a number field can not contain spaces to begin with, so you can not insert them via JavaScript either.

Comment: FYI: [`type="tel"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel) exists; insisting on using `number` here makes rather little sense to begin with IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to NGS-MASK https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/ you will find the best solution to achieve what you are looking for :)

Comment: I normally don't like it when people suggest frameworks, but adding spaces in numbers is so time consuming and gives so little in return. It sounds simple, and then you realize that people wants to remove characters as well.

Comment: Yes i know is so timing consuming, but sometimes the client ask for something and need to realize without understand is time consuming

Comment: Did you try the ngx-mask module ?